# PHP - give exception Error on convert a 12hour format time to a new timezone

Tags: timezone, php

I use below codes to convert a 12hour UTC to a new timezone
***MySourceCodes:*** (part of my udp socket server codes)

```
// $gps_time = "9:43:52"; 
$gps_time      = $time_hour.":".$time_min.":".$time_sec;
// $time_received = "01:45:04 2012-07-28"; 
$time_received = date('H:i:s Y-m-d');

$utc = new DateTimeZone("UTC"); 
$moscow = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"); 

//Instantiate both AM and PM versions of your time 
$gps_time_am = new DateTime("$gps_time AM", $utc); 
$gps_time_pm = new DateTime("$gps_time PM", $utc); 

//Received time 
$time_received = new DateTime($time_received, $moscow); 

//Change timezone to Moscow 
$gps_time_am->setTimezone($moscow); /* ### ### Line 105 Error ### ### */
$gps_time_pm->setTimezone($moscow); 

//Check the difference in hours. If it's less than 1 hour difference, it's the correct one. 
if ($time_received->diff($gps_time_pm)->h < 1) { 

$correct_time = $gps_time_pm->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
} 
else { 

$correct_time = $gps_time_am->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
}

echo $correct_time;
```

***PHP Error :***

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (0:11:38 AM) at position 8 (A): The timezone could not be found in the database' in C:\xampp\php\udp.php:105
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\php\udp.php(105): DateTime->__construct('0:11:38 AM', Object(DateTimeZone))
#1 {main}  thrown in C:\xampp\php\udp.php on line 105
```

Error give when input time is `0:11:38 AM`
***Question:***
how can I solve the problem ?

***Edit:*** *my input time Source from GPS Tracker (change seconds to 12hour format time)*

```
$time_hour      = floor($get_time / 3600);
$time_min       = floor(($get_time - ($time_hour*3600)) / 60);
$time_sec       = dotwodigits(($get_time - (($time_hour*3600) + ($time_min * 60))));
GPS Time        = $time_hour.":".$time_min.":".$time_sec
```

Comment: I would add the timezone to the database as the error suggests

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing as `0:11:38 AM`. It's either `0:11:38` or  `12:11:38 AM`

Comment: 12-hour time doesn't have a `0:xx:yy` time, because that will always be written as `12:xx:yy` instead. The error is with the fact that you tried to pass an impossible time to `DateTime` at all.

Comment: @Palladium first post edited , I add my input source time converter from seconds to 12 hour format from GPS tracker , how can I correct the received time format ?       /*edit*/      now `GPS Time` don't have number 12 in time as `hour` , how can i specify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've pointed out in the comments, 12-hour time doesn't have a `0:xx:yy` time. What you can do, then, is check the value of `$time_hour` beforehand:

```
//assigning values to $time_hour, $time_min, and $time_sec
if ($time_hour == 0) $time_hour = 12;
//rest of code
```

This will prevent the invalid time from being passed to the `DateTime` constructor.

EDIT: This check can actually be performed during the assignment of `$time_hour`:

```
$time_hour = floor($get_time / 3600) ?: 12;
```

Comment: Thanks , now i just use `$time_hour = floor($get_time / 3600) ?: 12;` ?

Comment: @IR_Designer Yeah, that should do the trick. Note that I used the shortened form of the ternary, which is only available in PHP 5.3 and up. If you're on PHP 5.2, you need to use the full syntax instead.

Comment: Now Give Error at `12:-720:00 AM` time

Comment: @IR_Designer That would be my fault. I didn't notice that you need to use `$time_hour` after it's been assigned. What you want to do then is use the `if ($time_hour == 0) $time_hour = 12;` line right before you assign your `$gps_time`.

Comment: After that error ~ I use `if ($time_hour === 0) $time_hour = 12;` . before your last hint , but thanks for hint too ;)